# Configure wicket with spring without xml

Tags: spring, hibernate, wicket, spring-java-config

Is it possible to configure wicket with spring without using any xml files like web.xml???

Here is my already made and working configuration for spring+hibernate. I would llike to go with this direction and totally get rid of xml configuration files. Please help.

```
package com.rerp.common.init;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        // Allow to use Put and Delete method for REST architecture
        registerHiddenFieldFilter(servletContext);
    }

    private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*"); 
    }
}
```

**And WebAppConfig file**

```
package com.rerp.common.init;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.rerp")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_SERVICES = "services.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_COMMON = "common.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_CMS = "cms.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        //sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_SERVICES),
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_COMMON),
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_CMS)
                });
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));
        return properties;  
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of web.xml if you are using servlet 3 or a newer version. See user guide at http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/single.html#helloWorld_2.

To know how to use Spring as dependency injector see example project https://github.com/bitstorm/Wicket-tutorial-examples/tree/master/SpringInjectionExample

Comment: It looks promising. I will give a Try.

Comment: By servlet 3 You meant: `<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>` ???

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Then you have to use a web servlet that support this servlet standard (ex: Tomcat 7)

Comment: this link is broken: http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/single.html#helloWorld_2.  This is why link-only answers aren't a good idea ...

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to configure wicket with spring without using any xml files like web.xml???

Yes, that's possible.

Wicket uses a `javax.servlet.Filter` called `org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter` to boot Wicket, whereas Spring MVC uses a Servlet instead of a Filter. Because Wicket uses a filter, it is able to process the request before Spring's DispatcherServlet does. WicketFilter will pass request through when they are not Wicket related, so that the DispatcherServlet gets a chance to handle the request.

This is the solution in code:

## Add wicket-spring module to autowire beans

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
  <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
  <version>8.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

## Add DispatcherServlet and WicketFilter to the ServletContext in your WebApplicationInitializer

```
    public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            // Add WicketFilter
            FilterRegistration.Dynamic wicketFilterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("wicketFilter", WicketFilter.class);
            wicketFilterRegistration.setInitParameter("applicationClassName", "springwickettest.MyWicketApplication");
            wicketFilterRegistration.setInitParameter("filterMappingUrlPattern", "/*");
            wicketFilterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

            // Create Spring context
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext springContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            springContext.register(WebAppConfig.class);

            // Add Spring Context to ServletContext
            servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(springContext));
            springContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

            // Create Spring Dispatcher servlet
            ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(springContext));
            servlet.addMapping("/*");
            servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

            // Allow to use Put and Delete method for REST architecture
            registerHiddenFieldFilter(servletContext);
        }


        private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
            aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*");
        }
    }
```

## Add Spring injector to Wicket

```
public class MyWicketApplication extends WebApplication {
    @Override
    public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage() {
        return HomePage.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();

        // Get the SpringContext from the servletContext
        WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this, springContext));

        // Mount your pages
        mountPage("/test", TestPage.class);
    }
}
```